# Is there a way to format cells based on VBA reading unit type?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table. Row 2 in each column contains a heading for the unit type (such as $ values, per cent). I would like to format the values in the column based on the unit type in Row 2.

Currently, the macro selects columns manually. (See example below).

Is there a macro that would format the columns based on the unit type?

Instead of the macro below, then ''if row 2 is "per cent" then change column format to '0%'.

```
Sub Format()


Columns("Q:Q").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "0%"
Columns("AA:AA").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "0%"
Columns("AK:AK").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "0%"
Columns("AU:AU").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "0%"
Columns("BJ:BJ").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "0%"
Columns("BR:BR").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "0%"
Columns("BN:BN").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "0%"
Columns("BZ:BZ").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "0%"
Columns("BV:BV").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "0%"

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample (image) of what your worksheet looks like?  It's all possible but the devil is in the detail on this one.  It sounds like you want to format the cell, not the column.

Comment: You might benefit from reading 
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: @Pᴇʜ that's super useful thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to change the example code below to suit your exact requirements:

```
Dim lngCol As Long, i As Long
Dim str As String

lngCol = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For i = 1 To lngCol
    Select Case Cells(2, i)
        Case "$": Columns(i).Style = "Currency"
        Case "%": Columns(i).Style = "Percent"
    End Select
Next
```